# UX Approaches to Competitive Analysis for a University Branding/Communications Toolkit Website?

Tags: website-design, information-architecture, competitive-analysis

I'm being asked to do a "competitive analysis" for a university website that has communications and brand guidelines/resources. This is meant at as a solo project done in a few days, I don't have many resources at hand at the moment so user testing is out of the question.

The request was very broad and I was thinking of comparing our toolkit against other university's brand toolkits. Taking an initial look, the information architecture & site map could use some work...

What are some UX approaches/considerations I should take into account when reviewing our website and comparing it against other universities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably consider design heuristics if you're looking at the website from a usability perspective:

[Nielsen](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/)

[Gerhardt-Powels](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10447319609526147)

This Wikipedia article will give you a nice overview of Usability Heuristics:

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_evaluation#cite_note-5)

You could compare how each website meets usability heuristics, then perhaps complete a feature/content analysis. You could also consider researching the motivations of users (Students, Perspective students, Staff, Researchers, Potential employees etc) and maybe look at a user task matrix and see how each site meets the user needs. These are only suggestions, there are many more ways to analyse and compare webpages.